# Apache works on localhost but not on server name

Tags: apache, localhost

As my user id suggests, I am a novice programmer.

I am trying a simple Apache server configuration in ubuntu,

I have created below .conf file in /etc/apache2/sites-available/awesome.conf with below code. Also I have created a symbolic link in /etc/apache2/sites-enable and restarted the Apache.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
ServerName www.myawesome.org

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/awesome
DirectoryIndex hello.php


# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

when I access localhost/awesome/hello.php I get the desired text "Hello World".

But when I type www.myawesome.org it dispays below message: 
"Server not found"

Any help/guidance is appreciated.

Regards....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to edit the hosts file and add the ServerName here pointing to localhost

Open hosts file with:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

...and at the end of this file add:

```
127.0.0.1 www.myawesome.org
```

Comment: Thanks a lot starless you are really a star... :) 127.0.0.1 was taken by localhost so I used 127.0.0.2. Hope this is fine... The good thing is it works :)

Comment: How do I make the status of question as "Solved"

Comment: I am grateful to be able to help. To mark a question as solved you need to click on the check mark. Check this image:  
http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png